# How to place data in a new column when it reaches 10 rows?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have this html code here:

```
<div class="bids_container col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">

@each('comp.bid_summary', $bids, 'bid')

</div>
```

My bids are paginated by 10. What I want to do here is when this column reaches 10 rows I want to start adding new rows in the new column next to it. Is this possible somehow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked Tykus answer, but it looks like OP isn't defining the column in `comp.bid_summary` so I think something like this is closer to the intended results:

```
<div class="bids_container">
  <div class="row">
    @foreach ($bids->chunk(10) as $chunk)
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        @each('comp.bid_summary', $chunk, 'bid')
      </div>
    @endforeach
 </div>
</div>
```

You would want to paginate by 20 to get 2 columns.

If you remove pagination and have over 20 results you'll get more then 2 columns, so you could `->limit(20)` before you chunk to ensure only 2 columns will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than paginating the bids which will result in multiple pages, you can return the entire collection and `chunk` it:

```
@foreach ($bids->chunk(10) as $chunk)
  <div class="row">
    @each('comp.bid_summary', $chunk, 'bid')
  </div>
@endforeach
```

The `$chunk` is a subset of the full collection